# How can I remove the blocks hidden by the stadium's structure?

Tags: trackmania-forever

The screenshot below shows that some blocks are hidden by the stadium's structure. How can I remove such hidden blocks in the Trackmania Nations Forever's map editor?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press the <kbd>4</kbd> and <kbd>6</kbd> numbers on the numpad keyboard, your view in the editor rotates, which should make you able to remove these blocks.

Answer (score -1):

Hold down the mouse wheel button (button 3) and move the mouse and the camera should move